# Condition for minimum projectile velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

So I was solving the following problem

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237497/somewhat-unusual-projectile-motion-question

and the minimum velocity involves the projectile intersecting the top of both walls, but I can't seem to understand why this has to be the case for minimum launch speed. Perhaps there is a visually intuitive way of understanding this condition but I can't seem to catch on to one.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

From the movement kinematics we can obtain

$$
h = h_0 + \frac{v_y}{v_x} x -\frac 12\frac{g}{v_x^2} x^2
$$

where $v_0 = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$ is the initial velocity.

Considering the movement origin at the top of the first wall we have the problem

$$
\min_{v_x,v_y} \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \frac{v_y}{v_x}\Delta x -\frac 12\frac{g}{v_x^2}\Delta x^2 = \Delta h
$$

with $\Delta x = x_2-x_1$. 
This problem is equivalent to

$$
\min_{v_x,v_y} \left(v_x^2+v_y^2\right)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \  \frac{v_y}{v_x}\Delta x -\frac 12\frac{g}{v_x^2}\Delta x^2 = \Delta h
$$

The lagrangian is

$$
L(v_x,v_y,\lambda) = \left(v_x^2+v_y^2\right)+\lambda\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\Delta x -\frac 12\frac{g}{v_x^2}\Delta x^2 - \Delta h\right)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 v_x^4-\lambda  \Delta x v_y v_x+g \lambda  \Delta
   x^2&=&0 \\
 \frac{\lambda  \Delta x}{v_x}+2 v_y & = & 0\\
 \Delta h+\frac{\Delta x \left(g \Delta x-2 v_x
   v_y\right)}{2 v_x^2} & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

This system can be easily solved. Note that $v_xv_y = -\frac 12\lambda\Delta x$ so the solution for $v_0$ is

$$
v_0^2 = \left(\Delta h + \sqrt{\Delta h^2+\Delta x^2}\right)g
$$

or

$$
v_0^2 = \left(\Delta h + L\right)g
$$

Here $v_0$ is the initial velocity at the origin in the top of $h_1$, assuming $h_1 \le h_2$. Now considering $V_0$ as the initial velocity at ground, and knowing that $\frac 12V_0^2 = \frac 12 v_0^2 + gh_1$ we have finally

$$
V_0^2 = v_0^2 + 2g h_1 = \left(h_1+h_2+L\right)g
$$

NOTE

We can solve this minimization problem, by substituting into $v_x^2+v_y^2$ the relationship $v_x = f(v_y)$ or $v_y = g(v_x)$ obtained from

$$
\frac{v_y}{v_x}\Delta x -\frac 12\frac{g}{v_x^2}\Delta x^2 = \Delta h
$$

and then minimizing

$$
v_0^2 = f(v_y)^2+v_y^2
$$

regarding $v_y$